# What will be the Javascript code for this for changing the ID of each tag while making a clone every time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I want to clone the template and show it to the `<div id= "wrapper">` with different ID every time I make a clone. When I press the add-new-project button a new template is shown with different "ID" every time.

Javascript code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var cloneCntr = 1;
    var i = 0;
    $("#projectData").on('click', function () {


        $('template').children().each(function () {
            this.id = this.id+ this.i;
        });
        var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
        var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
        i++;
        $('#wrapper').append(clon);
      });
  });
```

Html code:

```
 <form id="projectForm">
        <div class="container">
  //////  ---------------------code-------////           <br>
            <br>
            <h4>Project Experience</h4>
            <hr>
            <template id="template">

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-row">
---------Template Code-------
                    </div>

                </div>

                <hr>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper" class="container">

            </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" id="projectData" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Project</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to replace every tag "id" in the template, every time when I make a clone of this.

Comment: `this.i` does not work. I guess you want `i++` instead.

Comment: yes, I have already changed that. But it is not working for me.  I want to change all ID of input tags inside the new cloned template.

Comment: I see. In that case, you'll want `$(clon).children().each(…)` - your current code changes ids in *all* templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how this could work for you.

See a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/o76pqxyw/

Here's a screenshare, showing how the IDs change: https://www.loom.com/share/4a1556c4bb5c4422ad1d4b20a12a638a

#### HTML

```
<div id="template-form">
  <p><label>First Name</label> <input type="text" id="first-name" /></p>
  <p><label>Last Name</label> <input type="text" id="last-name" /></p>
</div>
<button id="btn">Add New User</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
const button = $('#btn');
const target = $('#container');
let counter = 0;


$(button).on('click', () => {
  const template = $('#template-form');
    const copy = $(template).clone();
  counter++;

    const elements = $(copy).find('input');
  $(elements).each(function(index) {
    const currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    const newId = currentId + '-' + counter;
    $(this).attr('id', newId);
  });

  $(target).append(copy);
})
```

Comment: this will change the id of all input tags inside the template?

Comment: This should only change the ID of the new one. Are you intending to change all IDs?

Comment: yes i want to change all ID of input tags inside the new cloned template

Comment: @Akash Updated my response above with an example in JSFiddle and a screenshare of how it works.